# VBA excel for existence of image format of type jpg

Tags: image, excel, vba, exists

Lets say that I have a spreadsheet in excel named test.xls and inside it a column named column1 with values image1, image2, etc. And I have a folder named images, contain images of type jpg, named like the values in the column image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc.
I need a Vba code to check if the images exist in the folder based on the spreadsheet column.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example will display the search results in another column. Edit the variables and don't forget the last \ in the folder path.

```
Sub checkFiles()
  Dim count&, lastRow&
  Dim folderPath, columnRead, columnWrite As String

  folderPath = "C:\EXAMPLE\"
  columnRead = "A"
  columnResults = "B"

  lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(columnRead & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  For count = 1 To lastRow
    Range(columnRead & count).Activate

    If Dir(folderPath & Range(columnRead & ActiveCell.Row).Value) <> "" Then
        Range(columnResults & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "File exists."
    Else
        Range(columnResults & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "File doesn't exist."
    End If

  Next count
End Sub
```